# regarding foodme project in github

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

hello i have a question regarding the foodme express example over github:

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var open = require('open');

var RestaurantRecord = require('./model').Restaurant;
var MemoryStorage = require('./storage').Memory;

var API_URL = '/api/restaurant';
var API_URL_ID = API_URL + '/:id';
var API_URL_ORDER = '/api/order';

var removeMenuItems = function(restaurant) {
  var clone = {};

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(restaurant).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key !== 'menuItems') {
      clone[key] = restaurant[key];
    }
  });

  return clone;
};


exports.start = function(PORT, STATIC_DIR, DATA_FILE, TEST_DIR) {
  var app = express();
  var storage = new MemoryStorage();

  // log requests
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));

  // serve static files for demo client
  app.use(express.static(STATIC_DIR));

  // parse body into req.body
  app.use(express.bodyParser());


  // API
  app.get(API_URL, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, storage.getAll().map(removeMenuItems));
  });
```

i don't understand where is the api folder. it doesn't exist and i don't understand how information is going in and out from there. i can't find it.

can someone please explain this to me?

another question:
there is a resource for the restaurant

```
foodMeApp.factory('Restaurant', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/restaurant/:id', {id: '@id'});

});
```

and in the restaurant controller there is a query:

```
  var allRestaurants = Restaurant.query(filterAndSortRestaurants);
```

and the following lines:

```
  $scope.$watch('filter', filterAndSortRestaurants, true);

  function filterAndSortRestaurants() {
    $scope.restaurants = [];

    // filter
    angular.forEach(allRestaurants, function(item, key) {
      if (filter.price && filter.price !== item.price) {
        return;
      }

      if (filter.rating && filter.rating !== item.rating) {
        return;
      }

      if (filter.cuisine.length && filter.cuisine.indexOf(item.cuisine) === -1) {
        return;
      }

      $scope.restaurants.push(item);
    });


    // sort
    $scope.restaurants.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a[filter.sortBy] > b[filter.sortBy]) {
        return filter.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      }

      if (a[filter.sortBy] < b[filter.sortBy]) {
        return filter.sortAsc ? -1 : 1;
      }

      return 0;
    });
  };
```

the things that isn't clear to me is:
how is that we are giving the query just a function without even activating it.
as i understand we should have passed the query somthing like:

```
{id: $routeParams.restaurantId}
```

but we only passed a reference to a function. that doesn't make any sense.

could someone elaborate on this?

thanks again.

Comment: Express uses a `:id` syntax within its routes. The route `/api/restaurant/:id` will match `GET http://domain.com/api/restaurant/19f9ajdsfnlaf` etc. `req.params.id` will equal `19f9ajdsfnlaf` while the handling function for this request is being executed. You can have multiple identifiers and name them other than `id`.

Comment: If you instead want to pass a query string, you would make a new route `/api/restaurant`, call it with `GET http://domain.com/api/restaurant/?idName=19f9ajdsfnlaf` and access it within your routing function as `var foo = req.query['idName']'`.

Comment: Actually upon reading more closely my comments might not answer your question. I am not familiar with angular.js so I have no idea what's happening when `return $resource('/api/restaurant/:id', {id: '@id'});` is called. My best guess is that Angular is setting up its own functions to execute when someone makes an API call to the Express route that represents that restaurant ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var API_URL = '/api/restaurant';
var API_URL_ID = API_URL + '/:id';
var API_URL_ORDER = '/api/order';
```

These lines are just defining string constants that are plugged into Express further down. They're not a folder.

```
app.get(API_URL, function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(200, storage.getAll().map(removeMenuItems));
});
```

So this function call to `app.get(API_URL...` is telling Express "Look out for GET requests that are pointed at the URL `(your app's domain)/api/restaurant`, and execute this function to handle such a request."

Comment: thanks alot that made things clearer but i added another question if you could please help me there also :)

Answer (score 0):

"api" is not a folder.

Every requests will pass through the `app.get` method.

This method will respond to the routes `/api/restaurant` as defined in the API_URL variable.